# Django multidb: write to multiple databases

Tags: python, django, django-orm

With Django multidb, it's fairly easy to write a [router](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#database-routers) that runs a master/slave infrastructure. But is it possible to write a router that *writes* to multiple databases? My use case is a collection of projects, all running on the same domain. To save users from registering/login in on every site, I'd like to synchronize the `contrib.auth` and `contrib.sessions` tables. Is that possible with Django multidb or should I look into replication features of the database system (MySQL in my case)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm working on a Django sharding schema right now.

i looked at the Django router but decided to roll my own.

some thoughts on your issue:

1. One idea is to use one database and then copy over the appropriate data via the use of Django signals on post-save.

something like--

```
import settings.databases as dbs_list

def post_save_function(UserModel):
     for db in dbs_list:
          UserModel.save(using=db,force_insert=True)
```

saving User objects (at least on a single-DB model) seems to save session, auth, etc. data under the hood via the various magic occurring inside django.contrib, so there's a chance you might not have to go in and figure out the names and types of all these database tables.

in support of the possibility of this working, I swear I read somewhere recently (probably on one of Alex Gaynor's blog posts) that if an object has a foreign key Django will attempt to use the same DB the object lives on (for obvious reasons in light of the way Django typically operates).

1. another idea:

from the example on the Django multiDB page you referenced I wonder if something like the following would work:

*their sample code:*

```
def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
        "Explicitly put all models on all databases."
        return True
```

*a possible modification:*

def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):

```
    if isinstance(model,User):
         return True

    elif isinstance(model,Session):
         return True

    else:
         ''' something appropriate --
             whatever your sharding schema is for other objects '''
```

looking at it again, this code would probably be more useful as the "db_for_write" function.  but you get the idea.

there are no doubt other types of model you would have to add to make this work (all the auth stuff, which is extensive).

good luck!  hope this is helpful in some way.

i'm interested in your findings and comments!

jb

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I didn't pursue this particular issue anymore, since we settled on an LDAP/Kerberos system to provide centralized authentication and single sign-on.

Answer (score 8):

i think you will be better implementing an SSO or OAuth service

but if you want like to synchronize your table users between two database and if you are using  your own UserModel you can do something like this

```
class MyUser(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)


    def save(self, ...): # ALL the signature
        super(MyUser, self).save(using='database_1')
        super(MyUser, self).save(using='database_2')
```

you can also putting with a decorator like this, like this you can also use it for synchronizing other tables:

```
def save_multi_db(model_class):

    def save_wrapper(save_func): 
        def new_save(self, *args, **kws):
            super(model_class, self).save(using='database_1')
            super(model_class, self).save(using='database_1')
        return new_save

    func = getattr(model_class, 'save')
    setattr(model_class, 'save', save_wrapper(func)) 

    return save_wrapper

# and use it like this:

@save_multi_db
class MyUser(models.Model):
      ....
```

Hope this will help :)

Comment: I would have to change Django's source code for this to work (as I said in the question, the tables I want to replicate are from `contrib.auth` and `contrib.sessions`). If at all possible, I'd like to avoid messing with Django itself.

Answer (score 1):

First, I think what you need is more an SSO framework, like [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662348/implementing-single-sign-on-sso-using-django)

I tried mouad's answer, but I couldn't get class decorator working ... And it seems to me this solution does not allow to have custom save() in models.

More appropriate to my need, I've defined a custom generic class and simply override the save() function.

```
class MultiDbModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for dbname in settings.DATABASES:
            super(MultiDbModel, self).save(using=dbname)
```

And then:

```
class MyObject(MultiDbModel):
    [...]
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        [custom save]
        super(MyObject, self).save(args, kwargs)
```

Comment: too bad db_for_write in db router can't return multiple dbs for write.. would be cool. The other issue is doing filter().update() will not fire save() so you could only use save.

Comment: This also doesn't consider saving related objects (FKs) for the object you are saving, if it doesn't exist in the 2nd db

Answer (score 0):

Here is my multidb_model.py which seems to handle foreign keys as well. Will update it if there are bugs but once you inherit from this class as per Stepahne's answer, this will handle foreign key saves.

```
import logging

from django.db import models

DEFAULT_DB = 'default'  # main postgres host
MIRROR_COPY_DB = 'pg_mirror'  # a copy original db, i.e. if you want to move your data and keep it in sync


class MultiPgDbModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwarg):
        super(MultiPgDbModel, self).save(using=DEFAULT_DB)
        try:
            fields = [field for field in self._meta.fields if field.get_internal_type() == 'ForeignKey']

            for field in fields:
                getattr(self, field.name).save(using=MIRROR_COPY_DB)
            super(MultiPgDbModel, self).save(using=MIRROR_COPY_DB)
        except Exception as e:
            logging.exception(f"MultiPgDbModel.save unexpected error when saving to pg_mirror, object id "
                              f"{self.pk} of model {self._meta.model}. {e}")
```