# Implementing Single Sign On (SSO) using Django

Tags: python, django, single-sign-on

I would like to use Django for implementing Single Sign On (SSO) for multiple applications that we currently use. How can I implement this using Django?

Comment: Are you already using a SSO mechanism for the other apps? Are they Django apps, too? (if yes, are they hosted on the same domain)

Answer (score 15):

We're using OpenAM.  http://forgerock.com/openam.html

The OpenAM Cookie means that the user is authenticated.

An authentication backend for this is pretty simple.  Under 50 lines of code.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#other-authentication-sources

We wrote a little bit of code that makes a RESTful request to the OpenAM server to get the user, group and role information.  We then use the roles to determine the user's authorizations.

Answer (score 14):

MamaCAS appears to be a good solution. (It has gained 104 stars at the time of writing.)

https://github.com/jbittel/django-mama-cas

> MamaCAS is a Django Central Authentication Service (CAS) single sign-on and single logout server. It implements the CAS 1.0, 2.0 and 3.0 protocols, including some of the optional features.
>
> CAS is a single sign-on and single logout web protocol that allows a user to access multiple applications after providing their credentials a single time. It utilizes security tickets, unique text strings generated and validated by the server, allowing applications to authenticate a user without direct access to the user's credentials (typically a user ID and password).

Answer (score 12):

Take a look at [django-cas-provider](https://github.com/Nitron/django-cas-provider) + [django-cas-consumer](https://github.com/Nitron/django-cas-consumer) (or [django-cas](https://bitbucket.org/cpcc/django-cas/overview))

Comment: At this point, using authentication libraries that haven't been touched in years seems like a bad idea, since new vulnerabilities typically come to light every year and things get broken as django comes out with new versions.

Comment: django-mama-cas is fresh and maintained http://stackoverflow.com/a/36539275/1783439

Comment: I dont think django-mama-cas isn't active now. It's been almost 9 months since the last commit. Issues have also been pending since. Looks like https://github.com/onelogin/python3-saml/ is being maintained.

Answer (score 9):

[django-sso](http://code.google.com/p/django-sso/) is a pretty neat package that implements single signon

Answer (score 7):

Django Simple SSO is another one.

https://github.com/aldryn/django-simple-sso

article about how to use this repo
[a article](https://micropyramid.com/blog/django-single-sign-on-sso-to-multiple-applications/)

Comment: given link not working....

Answer (score 3):

You may implement SSO as follows:

- Shibboleth as Identity Provider
- Django website as Service Provider

I've just finished writing detailed guide on my blog: http://codeinpython.blogspot.com/2015/11/how-to-setup-shibboleth-identity.html

Answer (score 3):

I have used https://github.com/onelogin/python3-saml with Azure AD and Google–pretty simple setup with great docs and support.

Answer (score 3):

CAS (Central Authentication Service) is a good solution that supports SSO (Single Sign-On) and Single Logout (SLO) for Django and Flask. Here is a setup instruction to have a CAS server and multiple clients with the same login/logout:

1. A CAS-Client is needed so I used the new generation of Django-CAS called [django-cas-ng package](https://github.com/django-cas-ng/django-cas-ng) and [here is its configuration](https://djangocas.dev/blog/django-cas-ng-example-project/) to make your own client. (Also, here is a [pre-configured client repo](https://github.com/django-cas-ng/example))
2. A CAS-Server is needed so I used a [pre-configured repo](https://github.com/django-cas-ng/demo-cas-server).

---

[**NOTE**]:

- It supports *Django 1.11, 2.x, 3.x*

---

[UPDATE]:

- It's also worth mentioning that, you have to change the default clients' `SESSION_COOKIE_NAME` in order to make distinguishable sessions to avoid conflicts at login/logout. In Django, you should add the following line in the `settings.py` for each Django client:

```py
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = 'client1_sess'
```