# How to authenticate from one server to another server in python/django?

Tags: python, django, authentication

Can anybody help me about how to login from one server to an another.. ??
(One application running on 127.0.0.1:8000 and another on 127.0.0.1:8001)

I have two django application. In one of them I have implemented authentication using rest framework. Now I want to implement authentication in another application using first application database (User table).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple Django apps, shared authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18230202/multiple-django-apps-shared-authentication)

Comment: Unless they're subdomains, it's gonna be hard. I've done it across domains, but it involved using a cross-domain request for a transparent gif to establish a 'logged in' session on both domains.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement token-based access control, i.e.:

1. The user authenticates against the first Django app
2. Upon successful authentication the server returns a token to the client
3. The client then sends the token to the second application with each request (in the request header)

You may want to use [Django OAuth Toolkit](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for that end.