# Managing multiple user base in same database table

Tags: python, database, django, administration, data-management

There is a Django project that my team is working on. It will have an administration panel to control several companies under it. To add a new company into the system, the admin will add the domain of the company using the panel. These domains will actually be pointed to our system. We will detect the company by url and manage the views according to that company's domain. For example: We will show the users under that company, do transactions under that company and so on. All information of companies such as user info, company details and members will be stored in our project's main database. Users will log in with their emails. Because of that, we cannot make e-mail field (or username) in database unique by using Django's auth model since email users can register to several different companies without them knowing it. My question is that what should our approach be for this situation?

The question we are looking for answers to:

- Set a random username to a user, but then we struggle with an issue when creating super user on command line after syncdb because the first parameter will be the one defined with USERNAME_FIELD. How to deal with this unique username field issue?
- Create different user tables for each company. If so, HOW to do this automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might run into some complex User / id management scenario.
Consider using some sort of single sign on.
There are several Django friendly solutions which help you develop an identity broker:

OpenID integration for django.contrib.auth
https://launchpad.net/django-openid-auth

I use OpenAm which supports OpenID
here is a post which gives some examples
[Implementing Single Sign On (SSO) using Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662348/implementing-single-sign-on-sso-using-django)

Django Social Auth
https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth

Alternatively you can try "Django Authentication using an Email Address"
http://www.micahcarrick.com/django-email-authentication.html

Comment: Probably I couldn't illustrate the situation clearly. Let me clarify it by examples: Let's say we have a table named Application, and there is another table named Users. There will be several Application and their all users will be in the same table called Users. Each user will be able to join several applications. But the applications won't share the users, each user will have different profiles (info) for different applications. We thought creating different tables for each application but how can we do it dynamically? Is it logical to create a user table to save all users together?