# Best way to redirect to another domain in django and be logged on new domain

Tags: django, session, authentication, cookies

How to redirect to another domain in Django from login view with auto login in the new domain at the same time ?

I have tried to set cookie with current `sessionid`  in `HttpResponseRedirect` to the new domain.

Any another ways, please ?

how to login to domain1.com, then redirect to domain2.com (domain points to the same ip) and be logged ?

Answer (score 1):

You're asking for Single Sign On (SSO).  It's a rather rich and complex topic.  There are some available django solutions like [django-sso](https://code.google.com/p/django-sso/).

Here's another stack overflow question on SSO with django:
[Implementing Single Sign On (SSO) using Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662348/implementing-single-sign-on-sso-using-django)

Answer (score 0):

If these domains are subdomains of the same 2nd level domain then you can use the [`SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#session-cookie-domain) setting:

```
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '*.somedomain.com'
```

If domains are totally different then you in trouble.  You can't set cookie for the external domain.

I think you have to create a special view on the second domain which will receive the `session_key` in the `GET` parameter and set the cookie for the second domain.

To prevent attacks you can store in the session some info about the user (at least the `IP` and `User-Agent`) at the first domain and compare this data against the visitor of the the second site.

Comment: thanks, but domains is different. Its not subdomains

Comment: I assume this answer only works if the database is shared between domains?

Comment: @warath-coder Yes. Moreover, it requires a shareable session backend.

Comment: So there is no way to redirect to external domain url and set a cookie ?