# Single sign on between different domain and platfomm

Tags: django, cas, openedx

How to achieve single-sign-on between two different domain and platform.
I have created a site in open-edx and use my other wordpress site as user sign in.

My issue is if I am login to wordpress site and open my edx site it should be logged in and redirect me to my profile page.

How can I identify in edx site that I am alredy logig in other site and take me to the profile page, like youtube and gmail.

Thanks.

Comment: Please [refer this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662348/implementing-single-sign-on-sso-using-django) may be help to solve issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a WordPress plugin developed by [eduNext](https://www.edunext.co/). You can customize the redirect part. 
Any other requirements you can enhance the plugin.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/edunext-openedx-integrator/

Basic structure.
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for such a great solution