# Using the CMS to edit content outside a course - openedx

Tags: openedx

I've installed a new theme for my Open-Edx installation and I'm trying to see whether it is possible to use the CMS to edit content outside of a course (for example - the dashboard)

Is there a way to do it? I was thinking about installing Django-CMS but it seems a bit shame as there is a content management system already operational on the instance.
This is also seem to be a bad practice to add libraries to the instance if I'm not wrong.

Another possible solution can be using the APIs or fetching data somehow, but I'm not sure if it's viable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are looking for different front-end for your instance.

For this question:

> it is possible to use the CMS to edit content outside of a course (for
>   example - the dashboard)?

In Open edX we use word "CMS" for "studio" interface. If you are referring that the answer is **NO**, you cannot edit/update the theme on open edX CMS(studio)

But if you want to use another CMS like, WordPress, Django CMS or any other CMS, you can use. Using open edX APIs you can build it.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50059937/single-sign-on-between-different-domain-and-platfomm/51054291#51054291) you can see an integration of Open edX with WordPress CMS.